# ¿Por qué recibo undefined como valor en el [(ngModel)] de Angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo un formulario, donde en el input tengo asignado el `[(ngModel)]= "authorValue"`, pero recibo "undefined" como valor.

```js
  authorValue: string;
  
  createAuthor(event: Event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // aca recibo undefined
    console.log('input value: ' + this.authorValue);
    this.author.name = this.authorValue;
    this.authorService.createAuthor(this.author);
    this.authorService.createAuthor(this.author).subscribe(
     res => {
     console.log('autor guardado: ' + res);
     },
     err => console.error(err)
     );

  }
```

aca el formulario

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="createAuthor($event)">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Nombre de autor</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="authorValue" placeholder="Ingrese nombre de autor">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se usa `ngModel` en un formulario el input debe tener el atributo `name`. Si revisas la consola te debe estar mostrando ese error.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createAuthor($event)">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nombre de autor</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="authorValue" 
      name="author" 
      placeholder="Ingrese nombre de autor">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```